# ACF Ordering posts by number field treated like a string

Tags: php, wordpress

Ordering posts by number field treated like a string. I have a custom number field (by ACF). and set my several posts as like 99 98 97 to show first in homepage. but the ordering after 10 is wrong. After searching i need to use orderby meta_value_num instead of meta_value. I have multiple meta values in the array. How to apply?

shown as: 99 98 97 …… 92 91 90 9 89 88 …. 80 8 79 78…

other example: 9 82 6 4 16 15 14

desired: 82 16 15 14 9 6 4

How can i fix this?

```
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
    
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
            'myordernumber' => array(
                'key' => 'myordernumber',
            )                    
        ));
        
        $query->set('orderby',array(
            'myordernumber' => 'DESC', 
            'date' => 'DESC'
        ));     

    
    
}


// return
return $query;
```

Comment: You can tell WordPress to treat the column as a numeric value: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38658/12496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *meta_value_num* instead of *myordernumber*

Look at this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Think should be:

```
$args = array(
    
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'meta_key' => 'myordernumber',
    'orderby' => array(
            'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 
            'date' => 'DESC')  
   );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Alt.

```
if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
    
    $query->set('meta_key', 'myordernumber');
        
   $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 
                                'date' => 'DESC')  );        
    
}
return $query;
```

Comment: i got 500 error. Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1409298432) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 584
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1409298432) (tried to allocate 24576 bytes) in wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1168

im using inside pre_get_posts https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

Comment: Because query not limited to post-type==post, so you get too many results, see above edits to solve.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'
for     $query->set('meta_key'=>'myordernumber');

Comment: my corrected code: `$query->set('meta_query', array(
            'myordernumber' => array(
                'key' => 'myordernumber',
            )                    
        ));

$query->set('orderby', array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 
                                'date' => 'DESC')  );`


this time it works as i desired correctly. thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use set('meta_key', 'myordernumber) instead of  set('meta_query', array(.... when you only have single key. My error was => instead of comma in set function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
    
    $query->set('meta_query', array('myordernumber' => array(                 
                'key' => 'myordernumber',)));
        
   $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 
                                'date' => 'DESC')  );        
   }
   return $query;
```

Related: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/